# Jython interpreter configuration failed in PyDev

Tags: eclipse, pydev, jython

I tried for an hour without any progress.

I'm using Eclipse Juno and the latest PyDev. Win 7. I installed Jython on `E` disk. When I tried to configure the Jython interpreter route in PyDev (Preference -> PyDev -> Interpreter-Jython -> Add), I get the following error (in a giant pop-up):

> Error: Python stdlib not found or stdlib found without .py files. It
>   seems that the Python /lib folder (which contains the standard
>   library) was not found/selected during the install process or the
>   stdlib does not contain the required .py files (i.e.: only has .pyc
>   files). This folder (which contains files such as threading.py and
>   traceback.py) is required for PyDev to function properly, and it must
>   contain the actual source files, not only .pyc files. if you don't
>   have the .py files in your install, please use an install from
>   python.org or grab the standard library for your install from there.
>   If this is a virtualenv install, the /Lib folder from the base install
>   needs to be selected (unlike the site-packages which is optional).
>   What do you want to do? Note: if you choose to proceed, the /Lib with
>   the standard library .py source files must be added later on,
>   otherwise PyDev may not function properly.

And they're three options available:

1. **Reselect folder**: which just retries and gives the error once again.
2. **Cancel**: not impressively helpful
3. **Proceed anyways**: This option is particularly weird. I clicked it and nothing happens. The Jython interpreter cannot be linked to PyDev

Answer (score 4):

The official install instructions did not quite work for me: http://www.jython.org/jythonbook/en/1.0/JythonIDE.html

Here are my findings how to make Jython run in Eclipse (I am using Kepler *4.3.1.M20130911-1000*, *PyDev 2.7.5.2013052819*):

- download jython **standalone jar** (e.g. versions *2.5.3* or *2.7-b1*)

  - **http://jython.org/downloads.html**
  - hint: the Eclipse PyDev distributed *pydev-jython.jar* seems not a valid jython distro
    (e.g. `eclipse/plugins/org.python.pydev.jython_2.7.5.2013052819/pydev-jython.jar`)

    - it will throw some: `NoClassDefFoundError: org/python/pydev/core/ObjectsPool$ObjectsPoolMap` (which is actually included in e.g. `eclipse/plugins/org.python.pydev_2.7.5.2013052819/core.jar`)

...

- *Window->Preferences->PyDev->Interpreter Jython->New->* select **`jython-standalone-xxx.jar`**

  - deselect all suggested folders (you could add them later if needed)
  - **ignore warning (mentioned in question above)** and select ***Proceed anyways***

    - the `/Lib` folder cannot be found because it is packaged within the standalone jar (`jython-standalone-xxx.jar!/Lib`) which may be ok later on

...

- adjust your newly created or existing projects to use this interpreter:

  - ***->Properties->PyDev - Interpreter/Grammar->Jython***

    - ***grammar:*** (e.g. 2.5)
    - ***interpreter:*** (e.g. *jython-standalone-2.5.3.jar*) (usually should be >= grammar version)

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how Jython behaves on Windows, so this is just a wild guess:

First time you run Jython, it usually does some basic library configuration. Try running the Jython.jar on its own once before adding it to PyDev.

Answer (score 0):

Before configuring interpreter for jython, Please make sure to choose type of language as python/jython" in the new project folder.